# Iptables redirect outside requests to 127.0.0.1 (VirtualBox)

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, iptables

I have a virtual machine installed with the output:

`ifconfig`:

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
inet6 fe80::e7a2:d6ce:7f7:aff3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
ether 08:00:27:f4:ab:df  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 29809  bytes 15340289 (14.6 MiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 28836  bytes 4186164 (3.9 MiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
RX packets 13485  bytes 3606497 (3.4 MiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 13485  bytes 3606497 (3.4 MiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

I run the command: `ssh -fND 8080 username@host` on this virtual machine. I need to route all virtual machine traffic through `127.0.0.1:8080` using `iptables`. How can I do that?

*I tried using the rule*:

`iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.2.15 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080`, but that didn't work. As far as I understand, this rule does not work for local addresses.

Comment: Sorry, what good is supposed to come of **all traffic** going through *8080*?

Comment: @tink The command `ssh -fND 8080 username@host` starts an SSH socks-proxy on the virtual machine through which I want to route all traffic.